# Why CLR doesn't throw an exception when AttachedToParent is not used correctly?

Tags: c#, .net

When creating child tasks, we do:

```
Task parent = new Task(() => {
  var tf = new TaskFactory<Int32>(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
  var childTask1 = tf.StartNew(...);
  var childTask2 = tf.StartNew(...);
  ...
});
parent.Start();
```

We uses `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` in TaskFactory's constructor. It is meaningful becuase all child tasks are created under parent's context.

but let's say we have the following code:

```
class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      var tf = new TaskFactory<Int32>(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
      var newTask = tf.StartNew(...);
   }      
}
```

We can see that there is no parent task in this console application, but we still create a "child" task by using `AttachedToParent` flag, which doesn't really make sense, and CLR should throw an exception saying "It is illegal to use AttachedToParent here" etc, but the program runs without any problem. So what happen if we use `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` flag incorrectly, does CLR just ignore it and replace with the default `TaskCreationOptions.None` flag?

Comment: I would guess that the task will behave in the same way as when `DenyChildAttach` is specified on a parent task - "_the child task will execute as a detached child task_" - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions)

Comment: [Attached and Detached Child Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/attached-and-detached-child-tasks), third paragraph.

Comment: To further prove @Martin 's theory we can use `Thread.GetCurrentProcessorId()` and see that child tasks are not limited to the same execution context when they cannot properly attach at run-time.